# Non-SQL API for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any sort of non-SQL API for talking to SQL Server? I'm curious if there is a more direct way to retrieve table or view data.

(I don't have a problem with SQL, just curious if any of the layer between the SQL parser and the underlying data store is exposed.)

Comment: There is definitely a layer; whatever OLE DB/ODBC drivers use, sometimes call Net Library, etc

Comment: "I'm curious if there is a more direct way..."  ==> SQL **is** the most direct way to talk to SQL Server :-)

Comment: @Christian well, yeah - this was more of an academic question than anything else. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as part of the actual SQL Server product, you'd have to install some other application to present/map the data in the manner you're after.  But that would probably have to use SQL to get the data itself, defeating your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for retrieving data is SQL, but if you're interested in the plumbing you could look at TDS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream

You could look at the FreeTDS library: http://www.freetds.org/faq.html